# Incrementing value of an integer in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextarea

I have the following code in which I have created a JTextArea and Menubar in which I have added menuItem Inc.

I have coded the value of "val" = 0 , so that when the code runs and frame appears, the first thing that is seen is zero. But i want to increment this "0" to + 1 when Inc button is pressed. Right know it keeps on displaying "0" when I press Inc
My code is as follows:

```
     public class Menu
      {
        public static void main(String[] args)
           {

           myFrame frame = new myFrame();
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.setVisible(true);
           frame.setSize(300, 500);
           frame.setLocation(600,300);
           frame.setTitle("My Menu");
          }  
    }
  class myFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
    {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        JTextArea area;
        JMenuItem inc;
        int val = 0;

        public myFrame()
      {

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20,15);
        add(new JScrollPane(area), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        String aString = Integer.toString(val);
        area.setText(String.valueOf(aString));

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Count");

        menuBar.add(menu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenuItem inc = new JMenuItem("Inc");
        menu.add(inc);

        inc.addActionListener(this);
     }
  @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Inc")) 
   {
    int result = val+1;
    String aString = Integer.toString(result);

    area.setText(String.valueOf(aString));
   }

  }  
}
```

Comment: Look at your console. You should see a stack trace of a NullPointerException. Analyze the stack trace, and try to figure out what is null and why it is. Hint: instance fields vs. local variables.

Comment: Read about [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `myFrame`s constructor, replace `JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20,15);` with `area = new JTextArea(20,15);`

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite your `area` variable.

Change:

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(20,15);
```

To:

```
area = new JTextArea(20,15);
```